# Using OpenGL for 2D

Tags: c++, opengl

I have started with OpenGL and learned about model,view,and the projection matrix. From my understanding the projection matrix is only needed to project a 3D entity onto a 2D surface(the screen). So if I want to create a 2D game would I even need to mess around with the projection matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. When dealing purely with two dimensions, you can leave the projection matrix as the identity matrix.

Answer (score 8):

It can still be nice to use a projection matrix for defining your coordinate system. By default a window will be defined between `[-1,1]` for both x and y no matter what resolution and aspect ratio. If you don't fix this using a projection matrix, you'll have to compensate in other ways. You want a square to render as a square, not a rectangle.

Depending on your GL version you can call `glOrtho`, construct it manually or use `glm::ortho`.

In my experience, working on the default `[-1,1]` system is extremely unpractical. For example : You don't want rotations around the z axis to deform your geometry.